# Redmineのガントチャートに担当者、開始日、期限を表示したい

Tags: redmine

Redmineでガントチャートの左側に以下の項目を追加する方法はありますでしょうか？
　・担当者
　・開始日
　・期限

右側のグラフに詳細が表示されることは承知していますが、
一覧として並べて確認できればと思っております。

以下のプラグインで担当者は表示出来そうでしたが、Redmineの
バージョン(3.3.2)が合わないようで断念しました。
https://github.com/stgeneral/redmine-progressive-gantt-mods

何かよい方法をご存知の方がいましたら、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redmine Gantt Plugin - Easy Redmine](https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-gantt-plugin) : 担当者と進捗率なら出せます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。担当者の表示は教えていただいたプラグインで試してみたいと思います。